# How to run the ocm-validator project (java)?

Tags: java

PS: It may not be acceptable to discuss the installation and functioning of certain projects here. But I have no choice.

In graph theory, the [crossing number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)) [image: cr(G)] of a graph G is the lowest number of edge crossings of a plane drawing of the graph G.

I see a Java project **[ocm-validator](https://github.com/TiloW/ocm-validator/releases/tag/1.0)**  that computes crossing number of a given graph.  And I'd like to see if I can calculate it successfully on my own computer.

- https://github.com/TiloW/ocm-validator

But after I downloaded it and put it on IntelliJ IDEA. I don't know how to proceed. It seems that the author packaged his project into **ocm-validator.jar**. So I tried to run the ocm-validator.jar,

```
java -jar ocm-validator.jar
```

but it returns：

```
Could not find or load main class ...
```

[image]

Therefore, I modified the text of MANIFEST.MF file  into

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: proof.Main
```

But another error was reported.

```
java -jar ocm-validator.jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
```

As a beginner of Java, I really don't know how to run this project. Linux and Windows are ok because I have a virtual machine installed.

My goal is to input a graph and quickly return its crossing number and return a drawing of its minimum number of crossings.

Unfortunately I didn't see a detailed program instruction manual on the github homepage. Although I've opened a discussion on Github, the project doesn't seem very hot. There was no reply.

---

**Edit: According to biiyamn's comment. I run the following command on Windows.**

```
 java -classpath "json-20140107.jar;ocm-validator.jar" proof.Main
```

The interface appears as described below. It seems to have worked.

```
   SYNOPSIS
  validator -f <file> [-v] [-s <solver>]

OPTIONS

  -f <file>, --file <file>
        Validate the proof contained in <file>.

  -v, --verbose
        Print verbose information during validation.

  -s <solver>, --solver <solver>
        Use <solver> as the linear program solver for validating lower bounds.
        Valid choices are {scip,cplex,gurobi}.
```

So I followed the instructions and created a new txt file called s.
However, the following command failed to execute.

```
 java -classpath "json-20140107.jar;ocm-validator.jar" proof.Main validator -f<file("C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\ocm-validator\\lib\\s.txt")> [-v] [-s <scip>]
```

The cmd returns the following information

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: you have to add the missing dependency to your classpath, it already exists in github repo json-20140107.jar and use this cmd to run your program :  java  -classpath "json-20140107.jar;ocm-validator.jar" proof.Main

Comment: Thanks. At this point it returns: Could not find or load main class proof.Main. I was confused. I saw that its Main.class was indeed in the proof folder in ocm-validator.jar.

Comment: Thank you, I succeeded in my Windows. But there are new problems. Couldn't find the file, I updated it in the problem.